# Proof of AIC criterion

Tags: model-selection, aic

I was recently read the book "Elements Of Statistical Learning" by Hastie et.al.
In chapter $7$, AIC criterion is definite as follows:

$$-2.E[log Pr_\hat\theta(Y)]\approx -\frac{2}{N}.E[loglik]+2\frac{d}{N}$$

Here $Pr_\theta(Y)$ is a family of densities for $Y$ (containing the “true” density), $\theta$ is the maximum-likelihood estimate of $\theta$, and “loglik” is the maximized log-likelihood:

$$loglik=\sum_{i=0}^Nlog Pr_\hat\theta(y_i)$$

but proof of this equation is not available in this book. I search about this equation but I can't find anything to understand it. can any one proof it in understandable way?

(equation $(7.27)$ on page $230$)

Comment: I think it is derived from Kullback-Liebler divergence, with some assumptions about normal (or exponential family) distribution of variation.